# Jquery Validation Error asp.net mvc 3 - jquery.validate.min.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am learning asp.net mvc and jquery. I have used jqueryui in my layout page, following is the code (using jquery 1.9.1 and jqueryui 1.10.3):

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // JOIN - REGISTER BUTTONS 
        $("#btnSignIn").button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-person"
            },
            text: true
        });
        $("#btnJoin").button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-gear"
            },
            text: true
        });

        $('a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#ddmenu li').hover(function () {
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
            $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
        }, function () {
            $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
            }, this), 100));
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Following is the code in my Login view, where I (believe I) have the valid references:

```
        @model LayoutTest.Models.LogOnModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "LogOn";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Log On</h2>
    <p>
        Please enter your user name and password. @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
    </p>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```

Referring to other SO posts, I have added the proper jquery script references, but I am still not able to get this to work. Attached is the error message I get when calling the Logon view:

Unhandled exception at line 48, column 199 in localhost:49436/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined

Comment: It appears that my question is closely related to the post here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818363/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-not-working-in-ie  unobtrusive validation for mvc3 seems to have gone haywire after version 1.8.3. Also as 2+ jquery does not work for IE8 and below, downgrading from 1.9.1 did the trick for me. Hope someone gets something out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my question is closely related to the post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818363/) unobtrusive validation for mvc3 seems to have gone haywire after version 1.8.3. Also as 2+ jquery does not work for IE8 and below, downgrading from 1.9.1 did the trick for me. Hope someone gets something out of this